# return different generics that implement same interface

Tags: c#, generics

Considering there is a method

```
static IEnumerable<IComparable> q()
{
   return new List<string>();
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same but on my own classes and as a result i receive casting error cs0266

I tried to cast this way `return (Common<Message>)new A();` but it results `InvalidCastException`

```
interface Common<T> where T : Message
{
    T Source { get; }
    void Show();
}
interface Message
{
    string Message { get; }
}
class AMsg : Message
{
    public string Message => "A";
}
class A : Common<AMsg>
{
    public AMsg Source => new AMsg();
    public void Show() { Console.WriteLine(Source.Message); }
}
static Common<Message> test()
{
    return new A(); //CS0266
}
```

How can the method return different generics that implement same interface?

Comment: Can you show some examples of what your passing in that works, and what does not work and where it does not work what your expected and actual results are

Comment: @SimonPrice This question already has all the information, what more could you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) which is why the first block of code works. To do the same thing you need to make your `T` type paramater covariant by adding the [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) modifier:

```
interface Common<out T> where T : Message
{
    T Source { get; }
    void Show();
}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
Common<Message> x = new A();
```