# Return generic interface implementation with different generic type

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I have created this simple generic interface:

```
public interface IInitializerSettings<in ViewerType> where ViewerType : Component
{
    void Apply(ViewerType dataViewer);
}
```

And added an implementation for it:

```
public class MenuSettings : IInitializerSettings<CustomGridLayout>
{
    public void Apply(CustomGridLayout dataViewer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Applied");
    }
}

public class CustomGridLayout : CustomLayout
{
    // The implementation code
}
```

Now I try to use it like that:

```
public IInitializerSettings<CustomLayout> GetDefaultSettings()
{
    return new MenuSettings();
}
```

But I get this error "Cannot convert type MenuSettings to return type IInitializerSettings"

I don't understand why it isn't allowed, `CustomGridLayout` inherits `CustomLayout`.

All I could find is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490565/return-different-generics-that-implement-same-interface), but this solution doesn't work for me (I can't use the `out` keyword).

Comment: *I don't understand why it isn't allowed, CustomGridLayout inherits CustomLayout.* but `IInitializerSettings<CustomGridLayout>` doesn't inherit `IInitializerSettings<CustomLayout>`

Comment: and obviously doesn't make sens ... `MenuSettings.Apply` expects to get `CustomGridLayout ` as parameter not `CustomLayout`

Comment: @Selvin so there is no way to make it work¿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you cannot do this is because for a contravariant interface (specified by your use of `in` for the generic type parameter) you cannot implicitly convert it to an instance of a less derived type. I think the bullet points [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) explains it fairly ok, if you think in terms of `IEnumerable<T>` (covariant) and `Action<T>` (contravariant).

As Selvin mentions in the comments the `Apply` method in `MenuSettings` expects an instance of `CustomGridLayout`, so trying to cast `MenuSettings` to `IInitializerSettings<CustomLayout>` is not possible because `public void Apply(CustomGridLayout dataViewer)` cannot handle a `CustomLayout` as input. Let me give an example:

```
public class CustomLayout
{
    public void SetupCustomLayout() { ... }
}

public class CustomGridLayout : CustomLayout
{
    public void SetupGrid() { ... }
}

public class MenuSettings : IInitializerSettings<CustomGridLayout>
{
    public void Apply(CustomGridLayout dataViewer)
    {
        dataViewer.SetupGrid();
    }
}


// Later in the code...

var menuSettings = new MenuSettings();

// This cast is what GetDefaultSettings() is trying to do
var genericSettings = (IInitializerSettings<CustomLayout>)menuSettings;

var layout = new CustomLayout();

// Looking at the type of 'genericSettings' this following line should be possible
// but 'MenuSettings.Apply()' is calling 'dataViewer.SetupGrid()' which doesn't exist
// in 'layout', so 'layout' is not a valid input
genericSettings.Apply(layout);
```

So in relation to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) you have defined `IInitializerSettings<ViewerType>` as a contravariant interface, but are trying to use it as a covariant interface - which is not possible.

Comment: Now I understand, I didn't thought about it like that. Thanks for the  detailed answer. I guess I would try to find different solution for that.

Thanks again :-)